# Setting up Android environment in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

While creating Android environment in eclipse, I receive this error:

> Folder can't be moved because it's open in another folder

, and when updating, it all fails as Eclipse doesn't find the SDK location, because emaluator.exe file is no longer existing as part of the tools of the SDK. I have preinstalled system-image, etc. Any ideas on how to fix this issue without re-installation?

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner and as now Google has their own IDE for developing Android App, you better should start your development journey with [**Android Studio**](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C7010856903). It is powerful, beautiful and very easy to use. Why you are using Eclipse still now? If you use Eclipse, you have to install Android SDK, Android Emulator. And you are getting all the tools in one place with Android Studio.
Moreover, Android Studio has **[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C4235140534)** engine inside. It is known as the best java ide. Super auto code completion, intelligent code inspector and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) has become the way to go for Android developers now-a-days. It is easier to use because is based on the IntelliJ Idea which is per se a much better java programming environment than eclipse, it predicts way better what you may need to write, and google has made it so that you have all your interface, simulator and code all in the same environment. On top of that google won't update the Android SDK to work with Eclipse anymore!